# PostgreSQL. Dynamically rename column in VIEW

Tags: sql, postgresql

This view return table with data on this year,

```
| cat_name | This year |
| cat1     |   12      |
| cat2     |   3       |
```

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_users_by_category_on_years AS 
> SELECT subquery.cat_name,
> sum(subquery."This year") AS "This year"
> FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT view_users_by_category_on_years.cat_name,
>    CASE 
>    WHEN view_users_by_category_on_years."YEAR" = date_part('year'::text, now()) 
>    THEN  view_users_by_category_on_years.summ
>    ELSE NULL::double precision
> END AS "Текущий год"
> FROM view_users_by_category_on_years
> GROUP BY view_users_by_category_on_years.cat_name, 
>
> view_users_by_category_on_years."YEAR", view_users_by_category_on_years.summ) 
> subquery
> GROUP BY subquery.cat_name;
> ```

but I don't know how to rename column "This year" dynamically to change "This year" to 2015 or 1992 depending on the conditions in WHEN.

Maybe someone did smth like this or knows how?

Comment: Views don't work like that. But look into pivot queries.

Comment: Short version, you can't. You'd need to generate the query as dynamic SQL. Look into PL/PgSQL's `EXECUTE` command and the [tag:dynamic-sql] tag. Also look into the `crosstab` function from the `tablefunc` module.